# Detect revoked permission for App in Google API

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I am using the PHP Google client library. I successfully get a token and refresh token from user/google to use with the API.
As soon as the user revokes the permission for my website in Googles settings on the Google page i get following error:

```
Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList: (401) Invalid Credentials
```

That is expected behavior since the user revoked my permission.
However, how do I detect that a user revoked that access?

Currently i do the following to see if i have access:

```
//$token json fetched from database
$gclient->setAccessToken($token);
if ($gclient->getAccessToken())
    //i should have access
```

Well this code unfortunately does not detect the revoked permission. How can i handle that?

Comment: After revoking permission, you will get an Invalid Grant exception next time you try to obtain an access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google APIs should only return 401 for lack of authorization. Since you had authorization before, receiving a 401 is a reliable indication that the user has revoked access.

Are you looking for a detection mechanism that notifies you of such changes before you make the API call? Today there is not a push notification mechanism from Google that can inform your application of such events. Of course, a pull-based mechanism is not useful -- you can simply make the API call and handle the 401 more efficiently.

Comment: That's not an answer, that's a comment :/

Answer (score 4):

Once you have detected that the user has revoked the permission you can ask the user to grant the permission again.

To detect that the grant has been revoked: Provided that you had authorization before,

- Making an API call using a revoked `access_token` will result in a response with status code **401**. Like this

  ```js
  {
    "error": {
      "errors": [
        {
          "domain": "global",
          "reason": "authError",
          "message": "Invalid Credentials",
          "locationType": "header",
          "location": "Authorization"
        }
      ],
      "code": 401,
      "message": "Invalid Credentials"
    }
  }
  ```
- Attempting to refresh a token after the revocation will result in a response with a **400** status code and an `invalid_grant` message. Just as specified in the [RFC 6749, Section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2)

> invalid_grant The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization
> code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is
> invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection
> URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
> another client.

Here is an example of such response:

```js
    {
       "error" : "invalid_grant"
    }
```

Comment: any particular api to call for the first response? php sdk?