# Is there a way to detect revoked permissions through Google APIs?

Tags: google-account

We're trying to find a way to detect revoked permissions through Google APIs without continuously polling the provider to get status updates. Does Google have any sort of notification system for this (a webhook, etc)?

The [most recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618275/detect-revoked-permission-for-app-in-google-api) I found regarding this was over 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Look here and search for Check For Permissions

[Android Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html)

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
}
}
```

Comment: Hey, your link is broken. Also, you haven't provided any context. We aren't using android or java, we're using node.

Comment: Strange, I copied the url exactly, it is updated now (the issue was http/https difference) https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html. For node I am not sure